# How to logout in asp.net using a html button?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, master-pages

I've created a masterpage where there is a button named sign out. How can I use that button in order to sign out or logout from the current login session.

Here is the button code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just give the href value of logout page. `href="Logout.aspx"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this logout code.

```
<a href="LogOut.aspx" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
```

**LogOut.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Loggin Out Please Wait" runat="server" />
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Logout.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        try
        {
            Session.Abandon();
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
            Response.Expires = -1000;
            Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
            //Response.Redirect("login.aspx", true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: Timer Tick function I've to put in logout.aspx code behind? Or i've to add timer in my master page and add this code?

Comment: There is no need for Timer .

Comment: Timer Tick Code put in Logout Page.

Comment: Master Page add only link in logout page all code are Logout page.

Comment: Timer tick use only after 5 second logout your page and all session expire.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using forms authentication, it can be done in one line:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

though I would probably add after it:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

**logout.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="logout.aspx.cs" Inherits="logout" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Logout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Logout successful."></asp:Label>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/index.aspx">
            You will redirect in 5 seconds. If you didnt, click here to redirect.</asp:HyperLink>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**logout.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class logout : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "5;url=index.aspx");
    }
}
```